# why cant minutes be typed into jquery time picker?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am implementing jquery time picker...here is an example. Sorry about format:

http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/sBJkf/3/

But when you type in 0830 it doest type in minutes??

i want to be able to type in 0845 etc...

If i take out the step 15 minutes it works, but i want it to step 15 minutes and be able to type in every 15 min etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the latest version from http://trentrichardson.com/. Your version is 0.9.8 or 1.0.0. Now there is 1.0.5 out. Im not sure if this bug was fixed but I hope it helps.

Comment: afraid it still has the same issue

Comment: Here is a [link to developer version](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/blob/master/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js). If you include this into your page, it should be easier to sort out the problem. 

My guess is that there is an unnecessary timeout set by the plugin which constantly corrects the date. When I managed to type quicky enough, and I was lucky, the timeout allowed me to enter 0845. :)